# Hiding elements when the elements has property data-mage-init

Tags: magento2, css

I found some elements will be preloading, when it is preloading, there is a property data-mage-init inside the tag .eg the menu bar in my custom theme

```
<div class="section-items nav-sections-items" data-mage-init="{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}">
```

after it is loaded, it will be changed to

```
<div class="section-items nav-sections-items mage-tabs-disabled" role="tablist">
```

How can i hiding the element if the elements contain data-mage-init=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CSS to do it, data attributes are valid selectors in CSS. Something like:

```
[data-mage-init] {
    display: none;
}
```

should do the trick. There's a great piece on CSS Tricks about using this kind of selector https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/